# Cleaning used frying oil with salt water : what is the point of using salt?

Tags: polarity, purification

In the process of making soap from used frying oil, I need to purify the oil.

I filtered the cooking oil but I also want to remove the polar compounds that are formed during frying : free fatty acids, monoglycerides, diglycerides.

To do so, I've seen that I can separate the polar compounds from the oil using a salt water solution (sources : [1](https://grasasyaceites.revistas.csic.es/index.php/grasasyaceites/article/view/175/175), [2](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-purify-cooked-oil-chemically)).
The process is slightly different in the 2 sources but it always consist of mixing salt water in the oil and letting it rest until water and oil separates, and that impurties will be in the salt water.

I understand we use water so that it can "catch" the polar compounds from the oil, but what could be the role of the salt in this process ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Salt can increase solubility of some proteins: https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/bch_332_lectures_3_and_4.pdf

Comment: Search the concepts of salting-in and salting-out.

Comment: So we have here a salting-in process ?

In the meantime, I found [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S101836391830655X) that says that adding salt allows to reduce the interfacial tension beetween water and oil. This also seems good for mixing the 2 more easily..

Comment: Additionally, the two phases can layer back easily